# How can I find out a users name and role in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there some way that I can find a user and user's role in MVC ? Also can a user in .Net have more than one role at once?

Comment: Don't mean to be facetious but it rather depends on how you are storing your users and roles

Comment: are you using asp.net membership???

Comment: yes I am using asp.net membership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard ASP.NET way:

```
  public ActionResult Test()
  {
    if (User.IsInRole("role name"))
    {
      //do something
    }
    return View();
  }
```

And yes, a user can be in more than one role.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe I didn't explain myself well. I would like to find out the current user and the roles of that user from within my MVC code. Thanks.

Comment: When you are in a controller you have a property named User (the one I use in the code block)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
string username = Page.User.Identity.Name;
string[] roles =Roles.GetRolesForUser(username);
```

Hope It Helps. Good Luck.

Comment: You need to add `using System.Web.Security;` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the User & its role (Identity & Principle) object in `HttpContext` object as follows

```
HttpContext.User
HttpContext.User.Identity
```

You will have to overrider onauthorize method on basecontroller something like this

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            //filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity  
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
}
```